# Java Memory leak for a old application

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I encounter out of memory exception for an old java application that i am using, are there any tools that will help me figure out what part of the application is leading to out of memory exception?

Most tools seem to be built for a web based java applications..

My application is not a web based application, therefor do not have the luxury of creating WAR files and EAR files and then running the tools for memory leaks on them.

Does any one know of a tool for such applications?

Comment: JVisualVM is a pretty good analysis tool, and is included with your Java distribution.

Comment: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html is decent, used it before and found the problem I had. I'd probably try with JVisualVM first though

Comment: Your stack trace is a good place to start.  You may just be attempting a local allocation that is huge, instead of running into a leaky retained object....

Answer (score 3):

Some basic tools included with your JDK :

- jps -l : to get the PID of your Java process. Then,
- jmap -histo:live  : to get the number and memory usage by class, so you can spot which is the more likely to cause your memory leak

You can also use HPROF, a profiler embedded in the JVM. Quite easy to use, no code change required, just a few command-line options. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html) for usage. 
You can read hprof's logs "by hand" or use a tool such as HPJmeter (not Apache JMeter) to draw nice graphs and such. Any commercial profiler can also process HPROF's output.

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the JVM start parameters, have it dump a heap file on OutOfMemory, and analyze it using Eclipse's [Memory Analysis Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). The parameter for HotSpot JVMs is `-XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`. To specify the location of this file, use `-XX:HeapDumpPath=<path_to_save>`.

Comment: Add the HeapDumpPath arg to your answer - and it becomes really nifty.

Comment: Good point, I believe the default is to put a `java-<pid>.hprof` file in the directory the application runs from.

Answer (score 0):

One more tool you can try is [Plumbr](http://plumbr.eu). It is meant to find memory leaks in any java based application.

Answer (score -1):

[yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/) is as good as it gets! Try it out! there are even simple tutorials given for it. but you will have to buy the tool

Comment: ummm... may I know the reason for downvote so I can understand my mistake?